# how to optimize a portfolio to a risk level

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio

I am trying to optimize a portfolio to achieve maximum returns at different risk levels eg, 6%, 9% , 12% ....
I have manage to make efficient frontier but i want to have some constraints on the std, eg
0.075 > std > 0.045

I have managed to find the weights to the minimum std

I need help setting the constraints and i need to be able to see the weights when the std = 0.06

the code i am using for the simulation for the efficient frontier is returns = [ ]

```
returns = [ ]
std = []
w = []

for i in range(50000000):
    weight = weightscreater(df)
    returns.append(portfolioreturn(weight))
    std.append(portfoliostd(weight))
    w.append(weight)

w[std.index(min(std))]
```

Comment: In general, a risk constraint is non-convex. One way would be to use a global solver. Instead, I think I would form the efficient frontier and then just pick the closest portfolio on the frontier (or maybe do some interpolation).

Comment: The thing is the risk level of the portfolio has to be between 4.5 % to 7.5% with 6 % being the most optimal. Is there a better way i can do this or?

Comment: Yes, construct a proper efficient frontier (with more points). It should allow you to pick a solution closer to 7.5% risk allowing more expected returns.

Comment: I hope you did not construct your efficient frontier using just random portfolios. You should use a proper optimization model.